# Building up an array before submission

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm building a front-end part of my dialogue app, using react. I want to create a form in which a user can add more fields and push these fields into an array, building it up before he/she can actually submit. 
So my object looks loke this.
[image]

Parts array should be pushed with a new object whenever a user clicks a plus button. Please, see picture below.

[image]

What I get at the moment get is that whenever I click the plus button it creates another object with one object in the parts array, removing previous one. See the code below, please.

```
addMoreFields() {
    const newField = {
      id: 'dialogue03'
    };
    newField.parts = [];
    newField.parts.push({
      text: this.state.text,
      speaker: this.state.speaker,
      prompt: this.state.prompt,
      helperFirst: this.state.helperFirst,
      helperTarget: this.state.helperTarget
    });
    //const joined = this.state.dialogues.concat(newField);
    //this.setState({ dialogues: joined });
    //console.log(this.state.dialogues);
    console.log(newField);
    this.setState({
      id: '',
      text: '',
      speaker: '',
      prompt: '',
      helperFirst: '',
      helperTarget: ''
    });
  }
```

This is how my whole object looks like.

```
const lines = [
  {
    id: 'dialogue1',
    parts: [
      {
        text: `как дела?`,
        audio: 'audio/аудио1.mp3',
        prompt: '',
        speaker: 1,
        id: 1
      },
      {
        text: 'у меня все хорошо, а как ты?',
        audio: 'audio/аудио2.mp3',
        prompt: 'Say that: I am OK, how about you?',
        speaker: 2,
        id: 2,
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: "I'm all right",
            word_target: 'У меня все хорошо'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'And you?',
            word_target: 'А как ты?'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'у меня тоже неплохо, кстати а что ты делаешь в субботу',
        audio: 'audio/аудио3.mp3',
        prompt: '',
        speaker: 1,
        id: 3,
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: 'Not bad',
            word_target: 'неплохо'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'By the way',
            word_target: 'Кстати'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'в субботу у меня футбол, а что?',
        audio: 'audio/аудио4.mp3',
        speaker: 2,
        prompt: 'Say that: I have football on Saturday, why are you asking?',
        id: 4,
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: 'Why are you asking?',
            word_target: 'А что?'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'Просто я хотел пригласить тебя на день рождения',
        audio: 'audio/аудио5.mp3',
        speaker: 1,
        prompt: '',
        id: 5,
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: 'Just',
            word_target: 'Просто'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'Wanted',
            word_target: 'Хотел (past simple form)'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'To invite',
            word_target: 'Пригласить'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'Birthday',
            word_target: 'День рождения'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text:
          'Ты знаешь в субботу у меня работа, к сожалению, я не смогу прийти',
        audio: 'audio/аудио6.mp3',
        speaker: 2,
        id: 6,
        prompt:
          'Say that: You know what, on Saturday I have football, unfortunately, I cannot come',
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: 'You know what!',
            word_target: 'Ты знаешь!'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'Unfortunately!',
            word_target: 'К сожалению!'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'Cannot',
            word_target: 'Не могу'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'Тогда как насчет воскресенья',
        audio: 'audio/аудио7.mp3',
        speaker: 1,
        prompt: '',
        id: 7,
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: 'Then',
            word_target: 'Тогда'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'How about',
            word_target: 'Как насчет'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text:
          'Да, давай увидимся в Воскресенье, как раз, у буду свободен весь день',
        audio: 'audio/аудио8.mp3',
        speaker: 2,
        id: 8,
        prompt:
          "Tell your partner: Yes, let's meet on Sunday, it just so happens that, I will be free on Sunday the entire day",
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: "Let's meet",
            word_target: 'Давай увидимся'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'It just so happens that',
            word_target: 'Как раз'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'I will be free',
            word_target: 'Я буду свободным'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'The entire day',
            word_target: 'Весь день'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'dialogue2',
    parts: [
      {
        text: `как ты?`,
        audio: 'audio/аудио1.mp3',
        prompt: '',
        speaker: 1,
        id: 1
      },
      {
        text: 'все хорошо, а как ты?',
        audio: 'audio/аудио2.mp3',
        prompt: 'Say that: I am OK, how about you?',
        speaker: 2,
        id: 2,
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: "I'm all right",
            word_target: 'У меня все хорошо'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'And you?',
            word_target: 'А как ты?'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'у меня тоже неплохо, кстати а что ты делаешь в субботу',
        audio: 'audio/аудио3.mp3',
        prompt: '',
        speaker: 1,
        id: 3,
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: 'Not bad',
            word_target: 'неплохо'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'By the way',
            word_target: 'Кстати'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'в субботу у меня футбол, а что?',
        audio: 'audio/аудио4.mp3',
        speaker: 2,
        prompt: 'Say that: I have football on Saturday, why are you asking?',
        id: 4,
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: 'Why are you asking?',
            word_target: 'А что?'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'Просто я хотел пригласить тебя на день рождения',
        audio: 'audio/аудио5.mp3',
        speaker: 1,
        prompt: '',
        id: 5,
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: 'Just',
            word_target: 'Просто'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'Wanted',
            word_target: 'Хотел (past simple form)'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'To invite',
            word_target: 'Пригласить'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'Birthday',
            word_target: 'День рождения'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text:
          'Ты знаешь в субботу у меня работа, к сожалению, я не смогу прийти',
        audio: 'audio/аудио6.mp3',
        speaker: 2,
        id: 6,
        prompt:
          'Say that: You know what, on Saturday I have football, unfortunately, I cannot come',
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: 'You know what!',
            word_target: 'Ты знаешь!'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'Unfortunately!',
            word_target: 'К сожалению!'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'Cannot',
            word_target: 'Не могу'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'Тогда как насчет воскресенья',
        audio: 'audio/аудио7.mp3',
        speaker: 1,
        prompt: '',
        id: 7,
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: 'Then',
            word_target: 'Тогда'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'How about',
            word_target: 'Как насчет'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text:
          'Да, давай увидимся в Воскресенье, как раз, у буду свободен весь день',
        audio: 'audio/аудио8.mp3',
        speaker: 2,
        id: 8,
        prompt:
          "Tell your partner: Yes, let's meet on Sunday, it just so happens that, I will be free on Sunday the entire day",
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: "Let's meet",
            word_target: 'Давай увидимся'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'It just so happens that',
            word_target: 'Как раз'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'I will be free',
            word_target: 'Я буду свободным'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'The entire day',
            word_target: 'Весь день'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

export default lines;
```

Comment: If you have time to study, i recommend using [`formik`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/overview). And it also have a tutorial on how to do something just like you are trying to do.

Comment: Do one this before pushing new object, copy old one and then push new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes the error is from your method `addMoreFields` each time is called you creating new object:

```
   const newField = {
          id: 'dialogue03'
        };
```

this is why you are not getting the last fields!
to fix it you need to create Field object  outside the function.
check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-cookies-p1gzm) for the answer.

Comment: Hi @adel, it looks viable, I hve not check it yet, will do it later, one question though. What if I will need my id to different every time. What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
this.state = {fields:{ id: '',text: '',speaker: '',prompt: '',helperFirst: '',helperTarget: ''}}
    addMoreFields() {
        const newField = {
          id: 'dialogue03'
        };
        newField.parts = [];
        newField.parts.push({...this.state.fields});
        console.log(newField);
      }
```

Comment: Hi @Bhawana, let me show my whole object, it is a little bit different from what you showed in your code I will update my answer.